# Android game with OpenFeint

Tags: android, eclipse, openfeint

Tell me how to properly implement the features OpenFeint in my game for Android.
I'm quite a beginner, so need help.

I spent the initialization OpenFeint, made ​​a button on the dashboard in the main menu of the game, everything works fine.
Can not get to realize achievements.

I do so (in the same class where initialize OpenFeint):

```
final Achievement a = new Achievement("1239817");

    if(mGameThread.mCurrentLevel >= 2) {

     a.unlock(new Achievement.UnlockCB () {
        @Override public void onSuccess(boolean complete) {
            Toast.makeText(main.this, "Unlocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            main.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            main.this.finish();
        }

        @Override public void onFailure(String exceptionMessage) {
            Toast.makeText( main.this,
                "Error (" + exceptionMessage + ") unlocking achievement.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            main.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            main.this.finish();
        }
   });

}
```

I think it's about the condition **if (mGameThread.mCurrentLevel >= 2)**, it somehow does not want to run.
I'm so if a player has reached level 2, achieving unlocked. In the game I was not very convenient construction, only one Activity-element, in which I initialize OpenFeint and achievements for the game, everything else is done in the class GameView (to upload data from other classes).

Help. Any ideas. Can achieve OpenFeint placed in a separate Activity? (Achievements.java?)

Answer (score 1):

What you've got there looks like it should be correct, and you should be able to split off the Achievement specific code to a different file if it makes everything easier to keep track of without a problem.

If you can't get OpenFeint working for you, check out [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com/achievements), which provides a very similar system (but maybe it makes more sense for you specifically) :)